# Clear clipboard with Scheduled Task

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

I'm trying to create a Windows scheduled task to clear the clipboard, but without success.

I know how to clear the clipboard using Powershell, and I know how to make a Scheduled Task, but I haven't been able to successfully combine the two. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have tried variations on the following without success:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "& {echo $null | clip.exe}"'

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 3pm

$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "ClearClipboard" -Principal $principal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is scheduled to run with the System account, but the clipboard is per user. You need to create a scheduled task that runs within the user context and only when the user is logged on.

I created a scheduled task with the following script and it works:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "& {echo $null | clip.exe}"'

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 3pm

$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "MyUserName" -LogonType Interactive -RunLevel Limited

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "ClearClipboard" -Principal $principal
```